# How to add button to the Security Role entity command/ribbon bar in CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm, ribbon, dynamics-crm-2015, crm-ribbon-workbench

I can't work out how to add a button to the Ribbon bar for the Security Role entity in CRM 2015.  I have tried both Visual Ribbon Editor (which worked fine for a similar task on the User entity) and Ribbon Workbench.  The problem is that neither of these 'see' the Security Role entity (though, again, they both see the User entity), so you cannot edit it.

I further notice that an export of a solution that had Security Role in it resulted in the following:

```
<RibbonDiffXml>
  <RibbonNotSupported/>
</RibbonDiffXml>
```

The problem is the original customisations to the CRM 4 version of the system DID include modifications to this menu bar, so we want the new 2015 version to be the same.

What can be done?

Comment: Try the application ribbon. It is used on every entity, but maybe you can hide it by default and only display it on security role entity?

Comment: Are you online (i.e. do you have Update 1?) or on-premise ?